# OOP design question - Avoid repeating code in similar classes?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm writing a bunch of classes in PHP for the server-side portion of a website we're developing. The classes look something like this:

```
class SomeEntity {
    // These fields are often different in different classes
    private $field1 = 0, $field2 = 0, ... ;

    // All of the classes have one of these
    static function create($field1, $field2) {
        // Do database stuff in here...
    }

    // All of the classes have similar constructors too
    function __construct($id_number) {
        // Do more database stuff in here...
    }

    // Various functions specific to this class
    // Some functions in common with other classes
}
```

The issue is there are a lot of these classes and they all need to have similar constructors and a few common functions, so I'd ideally want to write a superclass to handle all this stuff so that there's minimal copying/pasting going on. However, each of the subclasses has different instance variables and parameters, so what would the best way to design the superclass be?

(To phrase it perhaps slightly better, how can write a constructor function or other functions that do stuff with the instance variables of the class but without necessarily knowing what the class' instance variables are and hard-coding them by name?)

Comment: What are the similarities between the classes? Perhaps you should abstract those away into a class (or classes) of their own? Let the Single Responsibility Principle guide you.

Comment: Without a clearer understanding of your question, I can only tell you to put all commonly shared functions into a parent class, and extend it.  **Never** copy-paste code within a project.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm writing a superclass that's trying to abstract away the similarities but it's kind of weird. For example, the `create` function performs a query to check if the object already exists in the database, but the query it performs depends on the class (some classes have unique names, others have some different unique field, etc). I'm not sure how to generalize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go quite a ways towards a very generic "Entity" type class, especially is you leverage the various magic methods.

Consider class like this (just some random convenience methods for entity-like classes to share):

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractEntity {

  protected $properties;

  public function setData($data){
    foreach($this->properties as $p){
        if (isset($data[$p])) $this->$p = $data[$p];
    }
  }

  public function toArray(){
    $array = array();
    foreach($this->properties as $p){
       $array[$p] = $this->$p;
       //some types of properties might get special handling
       if ($p instanceof DateTime){
           $array[$p] = $this->$p->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       }
    }
  }

  public function __set($pname,$pvalue){
     if (! in_array($pname,$this->properties)){
        throw new Exception("'$pname' is not a valid property!");
     }
     $this->$pname = $pvalue;
  }
}


<?php

class Person extends AbstractEntity {
   protected $properties = array('firstname','lastname','email','created','modified');
}
```

Comment: Ah, this does seem like the most elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you separate anything you repeat into either a parent class, or a helper class.

If it's a common activity that relates to the object, and would apply to similar objects, you put that in a parent class and inherit from it. If the children of this parent have similar members/properties but are named differently for whatever reason, you just write the method to accept parameters then pass the different property names in the call to that method.

If it's a common activity that relates to the object, and only that object, it becomes a method in the child class which needs it.

If it's a common activity that doesn't relate to the class in question, then you create a new class that manages things relating to that activity, and write a public method in that class that your other classes can call.